# Safely increment a heap pointer in C

Tags: c

I know that incrementing a malloc'd pointer can lead to undefined behaviour. but what if I create a *"slice"* of the memory area? Something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *s = (char*)malloc(256);
    strcpy(s, "Hello");

    printf("%s\n", s); // Hello
    char *new_s = s+1;
    printf("%s\n", new_s); // ello

    free(s);
    free(new_s);

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I'm `free`ing the same memory region, I should be fine right?

Comment: `free(s)` is correct. `free(new_s)` is wrong. Rule of thumb: call `free` only on pointers that have been returned by `malloc` and relatives. Read the documentation of [`free`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/?kw=free) closely

Comment: You can use pointer arithmetic inside an allocated region, so it is ok. You can think it as an array. But you should not `free(new_s`)`: it is an error: you should free only what malloc (and relative) allocate. And when you free it, all region became *invalid*

Comment: for every call to `malloc` you should have at most one call to `free`.  I see 2 calls to `free`.  `s` and `new_s` refer to the same allocation; you should free `s` but not `new_s`.

Comment: @erik258 _"`s` and `new_s` refer to the same allocation"_: no, the don't. `s` and `new_s` don't point to the same memory location.

Comment: _"but what if I create a "slice" of the memory area"_: you don't create a "slice" (whatever this is) here. `new_s` just points one char further than `s`. Nothing whatsoever is created by `char *new_s = s+1;`

Comment: Of course this can't work.  Here's a challenge for you:  Write your own version of `malloc` that magically detects when someone has decided to treat a returned region of memory as several separate regions which can be independently freed.  You won't be able to.

Comment: @abberwocky erik258 didn't say they pointed to the same location. They said `s` and `new_s` refer to the same allocation, which is true. They both refer to the same block allocated by `malloc`. (Yes, they refer to different locations in that block, but that's not relevant to their point.)

Comment: @ikegami fair enough, you could understand it like that too.

Comment: Regarding "`free`ing the same memory region", the second call in `free(s); free(s);` would also be invalid because `s` is no longer valid after the first call.

Comment: Most/many impl of `malloc` are block oriented and put a control block in front of the returned pointer: `heap_control | ptr = malloc_area` In the control, there is usually the length of the area and of the previous area, etc. To point to the control area, we subtract the size of the control from the "public" pointer (e.g.) `struct heap *heap = ((void *) ptr) - sizeof(struct heap);` So, `new_s` would _not_ give the correct pointer. And, even if the impl could see this (and round it off) to work, the call would be a "double free" bug.

Comment: In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. You can use a second pointer to iterate over the entire region however you want. It's preserving some pointer holding the *original address* that is important -- so you pass the *original address* returned by `malloc()` to `free()` when you are done with the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incrementing a pointer that points to an allocated block is OK as long as the pointer points inside the allocated block.

Conversely, you cannot pass the modified pointer to `free` as it no longer pointer the beginning of the allocated block.

Furthermore, `free(new_s)` looks like an attempt to free the block that was already freed by `free(s)`.

There is no need to *free* whatever `new_s` points to, `free(s)` freed the allocated block and any pointers that still point inside it are invalid (dangling points) and must no longer be dereferenced.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you're not incrementing the pointer, you're changing what it points to.

Memory allocated in C, either array memory on stack, or pointer-array memory on heap, is always sequentially addressed, that's guaranteed.

So, if you are using s to reference your memory, you are pointing to the very first byte allocated.  You can simply print s+1 without allocating a new variable.

To answer your actual question, free() will not free memory that doesn't belong to you, attempting to do so is undefined, can cause memory corruption,and might also halt your application.  So, to that extent, the second call to free was a pointless one, the memory was already freed.

Comment: Sorry to have to say that, but every single paragraph of this answer is either inaccurate, meaningless, irrelevant to the question or blatantly wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the question was: In this example, I'm freeing the same memory region, I should be fine right? My answer speaks to that. Which part was inaccurate or wrong, please cite your references.

Comment: @Jabberwocky see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/ for malloc() explanation.